# leaflet choropleth map using dynamic value

Tags: javascript, leaflet, choropleth

I am doing a [choropleth map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) using leaflet and JSON data. I got a clean tutorial in [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com) site. In that tutorial the used [us-states.js](http://leafletjs.com/examples/us-states.js) JSON file where the choropleth was based on the `feature.properties.density` feature of the JSON if I am not wrong. If we see the JS file we can found there is a field called "ID" which is state id. I have a database where I have 5 different categories of data based on state ID. Categories are population, density, male_population, female_population, literacy_rate. I am calling those data through ajax and get a GeoJSON data state-wise as follows (Its a dummy data).

```
[{"state_id":"01","population":"123456","density":"1234","male_pop":"65432","female_pop":"57421","literacy_rate":"98"}]
...
[{"state_id":"50","population":"123456","density":"1234","male_pop":"65432","female_pop":"57421","literacy_rate":"98"}]
```

I want to integrate this data as choropleth value. when I call on literacy function the variation of color will be based on literacy_rate data. I can make the changes in getcolor function category wise.

Thanks

Comment: you have 2 questions here, how to integrate the two data? and how to color map dynamically?. You should split these into two separate questions.

Comment: If I get one answer I will be pleased.

Answer (score 1):

The literacy function should be like this

```
function literacy_function(){
    return {color:getColor(feature.properties.literacy_rate),
           other_options: options
    };
}
```